# Login on both Xampp and live Host stopped working but was working before

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

i don't know what i did wrong, but my script was working fine 24 hours ago, anyone with help should help me please. 
i did not remember editing it. it shows me this particular error
 *Wrong Password / Username Entered!*

i don't know if there is something wrong with my MySQL login details. but when i login as a user, it works fine and retrieves data. but this admin login seems not to work anymore. someone should help me please.
here is my **login.php**

```
  <?php
    session_start();
error_reporting(0);
include("../config/dbconfig.php");


if(isset($_SESSION['adminid']))
{
header("Location: admindashboard.php");
  }
if ((isset($_REQUEST['login'])))
 {
  $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['password']);
  $logid= mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['login']);
   $query="SELECT * FROM administrator WHERE username='$logid' AND password='$password'";
     $res=  mysql_query($query);
   if(mysql_num_rows($res) == 1)
     {

    $_SESSION["adminid"] =$_POST["login"];
    header("Location: dashboard.php");
      }

       else
        {echo '<script src="../assets/js/custom/sweetalert.min.js"></script>';
        $logininfo = "Invalid Username or password entered";
           }
          }

        ?>
       <html lang="en">
      <head>
    <!-- Meta tags -->
   <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
       <meta name="description" content="Khaytech Banking System">
       <meta name="keywords" content="Banking, Online, Piggybank">
         <!-- /meta tags -->
        <title>Customers Login</title>
          <?php ?>
      <!-- Site favicon -->
         <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../assets/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
            <!-- /site favicon -->

            <!-- Font Icon Styles -->
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/node_modules/flag-icon-css/css/flag- 
                  icon.min.css">
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/vendors/gaxon-icon/styles.css">
           <!-- /font icon Styles -->
               <!-- Perfect Scrollbar stylesheet -->
               <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/node_modules/perfect-scrollbar/css/perfect- 
              scrollbar.css">
              <!-- /perfect scrollbar stylesheet -->

               <!-- Load Styles -->    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/light-style- 
           1.min.css">
            <!-- /load styles -->

             </head>
            <body class="dt-sidebar--fixed dt-header--fixed">

               <!-- Loader -->
               <div class="dt-loader-container">
                  <div class="dt-loader">
                    <svg class="circular" viewBox="25 25 50 50">
                <circle class="path" cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke- 
                  miterlimit="10"></circle>
              </svg>
              </div>
             </div>
           <!-- /loader -->
             <!-- Root -->
                 <div class="dt-root">
                <div class="dt-root__inner">
                 <!-- Login Container -->
                <div class="dt-login--container">

                  <!-- Login Content -->
                 <div class="dt-login__content-wrapper">

            <!-- Login Background Section -->
            <div class="dt-login__bg-section">

                <div class="dt-login__bg-content">
                    <!-- Login Title -->
                    <h1 class="dt-login__title">Login</h1>
                    <!-- /login title -->

                    <p class="f-16">Welcome Administrator.</p>
                    <?php if(isset($logininfo))
                 {  echo "<script>swal('Error!', 'Wrong Password / Username Entered!', 'error') 
          </script>"; } ?>   
                </div>


                <!-- Brand logo -->
                <div class="dt-login__logo">
                    <a class="dt-brand__logo-link" href="login.php">
                        <img class="dt-brand__logo-img" src="../assets/images/logoo.png" 
              alt="Drift">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- /brand logo -->

            </div>
            <!-- /login background section -->

            <!-- Login Content Section -->
            <div class="dt-login__content">

                <!-- Login Content Inner -->
                <div class="dt-login__content-inner">

                    <!-- Form -->
                    <form action="login.php" method="POST">

                        <!-- Form Group -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="sr-only" for="email-1">Account ID</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email-1" name="login" aria- 
                     describedby="email-1"
                                   placeholder="Enter Admin ID">
                        </div>
                        <!-- /form group -->

                        <!-- Form Group -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="sr-only" for="password-1">Account Password</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control " name="password" 
                     id="password-1" placeholder="Enter Admin Password">
                            </div>
                        <!-- /form group -->

                        <!-- Form Group -->
                        <div class="dt-checkbox d-block mb-6">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1">
                            <label class="dt-checkbox-content" for="checkbox-1">
                                Keep me login on this device
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /form group -->

                        <!-- Form Group -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" name="go" id="go" type="submit" value="Login" 
                    class="btn btn-primary text-uppercase">

                        </div>
                        <!-- /form group -->




                    </form>
                    <!-- /form -->

                </div>
                <!-- /login content inner -->

                <!-- Login Content Footer -->
                <div class="dt-login__content-footer">
                    <a href="../customer/login.php">Login as a user instead</a>
                </div>
                <!-- /login content footer -->

            </div>
            <!-- /login content section -->

        </div>
        <!-- /login content -->

                </div>
              <!-- /login container -->

              </div>
            </div>
                <!-- /root -->

                    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
                   <script src="../assets/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
                 <script src="../assets/node_modules/moment/moment.js"></script>
                  <script src="../assets/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"> 
            </script>
                 <!-- Perfect Scrollbar jQuery -->
             <script src="../node_modules/perfect-scrollbar/dist/perfect-scrollbar.min.js"></script>
                <!-- /perfect scrollbar jQuery -->

              <!-- masonry script -->
              <script src="../assets/node_modules/masonry-layout/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
                <script src="../assets/node_modules/sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.js"></script>
                  <script src="../assets/js/functions.js"></script>
                 <script src="../assets/js/customizer.js"></script><!-- Custom JavaScript -->
               <script src="../assets/js/script.js"></script>

              <script src="../assets/js/custom/sweet-alert.js"></script>
                 <script src="../assets/node_modules/sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.js"></script>
                  </body>
                    </html>

              <?php include'footer.php' ?>
```

Here is my dbconfig.php

```
       <?php


         define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
       define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
      define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
         define('DB_NAME', 'ob');

         /* Attempt to connect to MySQL database */
        $link = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

       // Check connection
         if($link === false){
         die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }

         $con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
       if (!$con)
          {
           die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
          }

         mysqli_select_db($con,"ob");
          ?>


             <?php
         $con = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
           if ($con->connect_errno) {
          echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli- 
        >connect_error;
       }
         ?>
```

[image: here is my database, the login infos display wrong password]

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: _**Never ever** ever never_ store passwords in plain text! You should _always_ hash the passwords using [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and only store the hashes. Then you can use [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to verify a password against a hash.

Comment: Also, what PHP version are you running? The `mysql_*`-functions was deprecated back in PHP 5.5 and completely removed in PHP 7. You should refactor the code to use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead. Then you can also use prepared statements with placeholders instead of manually escaping the data before using them in queries.

Comment: i'm running 5.6, it was working fine

Comment: @Banujan Balendrakumar i'm getting Wrong Password / Username Entered!

Comment: Can you please echo your SQL query and result set?